# How to design a "Last Week Top played" rank with a SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have a player software. It have a SQLite database backing it.

I´m a SQL novice, and I´m guessing how could be the best way to do a "Top played" ranking.The top played could be from all time, last week, last month, etc..

I think in logging all music played along with the date and hour, and after do a Select with the date within the range, but it looks very heavy.

There´s a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is the simplest, so I would try testing it against a large log and see how it performs.  If it does well, then no need to complicate things.

If it doesn't perform well enough, then this is a more complicated approach:

If the Last Month is the longest time frame you will display (other than All Time), then you could have a log table that only includes plays from the last month.  Every time you play a song, add it to the log, and then regularly delete records older than a month (either every time you insert a record, or once a day).  That way your queries will have fewer records to deal with.  The Last Week ranking will still have to select on a date range, but it should be faster.

If that still doesn't perform well enough, you could have a log table for each time frame (TopLastMonth, TopLastWeek, TopToday, etc.) instead of just one that stretches over the longest time frame.  That way, the ranking queries will never have to use a WHERE clause, because they will always be summarizing all the records in the table.  Only the DELETE queries will have to select on the date, and these can be run less frequently.

For the All Time ranking, you will need a table with a record for each song.  Every time a song is played, increment the Times Played field.  Your ranking for All Time will look at this table instead of the log.

Comment: Yep, what i imaginated. Thank you !